# What means # (hash sign character, sharp) in typescript/javascript as a prefix for variable name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What does `#` mean as a prefix for Typescript or Javascript class attribute name?

```
export class MyFacade {
  #state: MyState = {
    isLoading: true
  };

  readonly #store = new BehaviorSubject<MyState>(this.#state);
}
```

Comment: The problem is it's not a sharp symbol (♯), it's a hash symbol (#).

Comment: Via existing reference https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/3001761

Comment: @James wow thanks! As a French speaker I was not sure how to call this one, and got confused by C# being called [C-sharp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language))!

Comment: @jonrsharpe it totally does but I spent way too much time trying to find the answer about this while the search-engines could not handle looking for a _character_... And now I know I was not naming the character properly.

Comment: I didn't try by searching [octothorpe](https://www.dictionary.com/e/octothorpe) though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash sign `#` means the attribute is private and is only accessible from within the class. This is [Javascript syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_properties) introduced by ES2020 apparently.

Typescript `private` is only checked at compilation when it transpiles to Javascript but the attribute can still be accessed and modified at runtime.

`myFacade['typescriptPrivateAttribute'] = 'newValue';`

[Source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-vs-typescript-private-in-angular-explained/)

Comment: Modern JavaScript also has private instance properties.

Answer (score 2):

in typescript or javascript if you use `#` before class attribute name like `#state` or `#store`, it means attribute is private to the class, so the attribute will be only accessed or modified within the class itself